# IOS https authentication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, https

I want my application to authenticate against appliance i.e passing username and password over https.

I looked at few examples and basically build the following:

```
-(void)authentication
{
    //setting the string of the url taking from appliance IP.
    NSString *urlString =[NSString 
                          stringWithFormat:
                          @"http://%@",appliance_IP.text];
    //define the url with the string
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    //creating request
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //setting credential taking from the username and password field
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username.text password:password.text persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];


    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace=
    [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]initWithHost:urlString port:443 protocol:@"https" realm:nil authenticationMethod:nil ];


    [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setDefaultCredential:credential forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];

    [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:NULL];

}
```

AS I use examples which I took I need some more understanding, NSURLConnection in the example above does not contain the username and password how do I add it ? so the request will also contain username and password or maybe there is better to pass that information.
Currently the request only contain the url string.

Thanks
ER

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When making a request requiring authentication, you will receive a callback to didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge, which you handle as follows:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
   if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
   {
       if ([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:MY_PROTECTION_SPACE_HOST])
       {
           [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
       }

       [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
   }
   else if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic])
   {
      if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0)
      {
          NSURLCredential *newCredential;

          newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:MY_USERNAME
                        password:MY_PASSWORD
                        persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

          [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
      }
      else
      {
          [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

          // inform the user that the user name and password
          // in the preferences are incorrect

          NSLog (@"failed authentication");

          // ...error will be handled by connection didFailWithError
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `NSURLConnectionDelegate` delegate to handle `NSURLConnection` events.

For authentication there are two delegates methods:`connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:` and `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:`

See examples in [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW1)